# Strange result with Pandas.equals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, compare

I have an initial dataframe `df`.

I use it to create an sql database.

Then, I create a new dataframe `dfsql` from my sql database with pandas.read_sql.

Using variable explorer, I can see my two dataframe are exactly the sames. Moreover, same columns and rows number.

However, when i use pd.equals to compare the two same columns "IdUnique" of the two dataframe, I have a false out :

```
In[4] : df['IdUnique'].equals(dfsql['IdUnique'])
Out[4] : False
```

What is missing to have "True" out ?

Comment: probably there is a difference between  'df.IdUnique' and 'dfssql.IdUnique' check the data once

Comment: More details will help to figure it out